# Updating a Table Column from a Count in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-like

I'm trying to update a column in a table with a result of COUNT from another table. Here is the code: (And it's working)

```
UPDATE software2
SET totalsoft = (
   SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM links
   WHERE sftwr = software2.softwarename)
```

But when I try to use the LIKE instance instead the = (in last line) I get no results... this is the code:

```
UPDATE software2
SET totalsoft = (
   SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM links
   WHERE sftwr LIKE '%software2.softwarename%')
```

Occurrences are 0. Any help?

Comment: http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/02/22/mysql-using-column-name-inside-the-like-keyword/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE software2 
SET totalsoft = ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                  FROM links 
                  WHERE sftwr LIKE concat('%', software2.softwarename, '%')
                )
```

If you put the column name in quotes then it will be treated as string. Then not the column **content** will be used but the static string `'software2.softwarename'`

Comment: Great! Thank you! Muchas Gracias.